# C# app crashes when using C++/CLR dll

Tags: c#, c++, clr

I have 3 applications one is a native C++ application which outputs a static library, one is a C++/CLR wrapper for this static library and finally a C# windows forms application that uses the C++/CLR wrapper.

When the projects are empty everything compiles and runs fine but when I add some code to my class in the native C++ application I get a crash in the C# winforms application.

Here is the error message :

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in      
WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in  
WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'stenCLR.dll' or one of its 
dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
```

I am sure stenCLR.dll is in the right folder.

Here is the full error log from visual studio :

```
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'E:\ST Projects\sten_svn\trunk\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe', No native symbols in symbol file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110_clr0400.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\db19194dcf61188e0e1bb9b6b2dba362\mscorlib.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tiptsf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'E:\ST Projects\sten_svn\trunk\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe', Symbols loaded.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\529187426262f016595cb4b92bc83241\System.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Drawing\6007a55278ac4372ab91f08ead86756e\System.Drawing.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\1242e9bc90b42762b6c7f2a5052a2280\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'ImageAtBase0x50d00000', Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'ImageAtBase0x50d00000'
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'ImageAtBase0x519b0000', Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'ImageAtBase0x7f0000', Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'ImageAtBase0x519b0000'
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RpcRtRemote.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'E:\ST Projects\sten_svn\trunk\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\stenCLR.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'E:\ST Projects\sten_svn\trunk\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\stenCLR.dll'
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll'
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll'
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll'
'WindowsFormsApplication1.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'
First-chance exception at 0x753eb9bc in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEFileLoadException at memory location 0x003bcce4.
First-chance exception at 0x753eb9bc in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x753eb9bc in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x753eb9bc in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x753eb9bc in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x753eb9bc in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'stenCLR.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

The program '[2000] WindowsFormsApplication1.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[2000] WindowsFormsApplication1.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2007/06/02/debugging-load-problems-using-fusion-log.aspx).

Dependency Walker will tell you if there are any DLL's that the one you are trying to load are missing.

Fusion Log Viewer will tell you exactly where the DLL is trying to be loaded from.

These are usually the easiest ways to debug library load issues as they make the problem extremely evident :)

Comment: When I open the exe in dependency walker I get this message at the bottom: 

Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

In the listview 2 files are read highlighted:
GPSVC.DLL and IESHIMS.DLL, I don't even know what they are.

Also tried running Fusion Log Viewer but it doesn't display any bindin g failures.

Comment: @BarisUsakli Just google them. IESHIMS.dll is related to IE (Program Files\Internet Explorer) and GPSVC.DLL is related to group policies (%SYSTEMROOT%\WINDOWS\System32\). Usually these are installed with IE/Windows, but you can see if this is your problem by finding them and copying them alongside your DLL and try again.

Comment: I will try that, in the meantime I am able to reproduce/fix the issue but it doesn't make any sense. If I put :
std::unique_ptr<D3DObject> _d3dObject; the c# app crashes if I replace it with 
std::shared_ptr<D3DObject> _d3dObject; it runs fine.
The header file for D3DObject is included in that file. (facepalm)

Comment: I was running dependency walker on my C# exe and I was only seeing those 2 dlls as missing. After selecting the C++/CLR dll with dependency walker, it showed the culprit. The missing DLL was D3DCOMPILER_44.DLL. Placing it next to the c# exe fixed the problem.

Comment: @BarisUsakli Glad to help. Both those tools can really save you time :)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that you have a 64 bit machine, compiled the c# application for 'Any Cpu' or 64bit and the c++ native library or C++/CLI is 32 bit.
In this case the system looks for a 64 bit library.

Ensure that all the application are built for the same architecture, x86 or x64.